# Не могу запустить обучение на csv файле. ML Net

Tags: .net, ml.net

Использую auto ml net. И не могу запустить обучения,выбираю файл csv и выбираю столбцы, после запускаю обучение и выходит ошибка:

```
Schema mismatch for score column 'Score': expected vector of two or more items of type Single, got Vector<Single, 1>
Имя параметра: schema
```

файл состоит из обычных слов и значения, например:

```
стобец;столбец1
слово;1.0
```

Comment: Он именно ругается на файл хотя он такой же как и другие, остальные файлы с другими датасетами работают а этот нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что было слишком много данных в Label столбце. Нужно было добавить больше разнообразия.